# ListViewAdapter - when listeners, attached to view are collected?

Tags: android, performance, android-listview, garbage-collection

I am using Custom ListViewAdapter for displaying, well, a list.
Each row in the list has 3 buttons, i.e. listeners attached.
But I am finding it very disturbing, that during each scroll the new OnClickListeners are being created, even for those rows, where convertView exists, as a non-null value.

// The most common approach to convert view, as I understand:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;   
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
    }
    final TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtProduct);
    textView.setText(name);
    textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ...
        }
});
... two more listeners, with the same approach
return view;
```

as per my experience with Java, Spider-sense "ting-a-lings" - seems that creating and throwing away the same listener approach is garbage-collector abusing.
I am not sure when the old listener had been collected, if it had...

Is there a way to use the old listener, instead of creating a new one? (some kind of cache data structure)

Answer (score 1):

You can set your List Adapter class to inherit from the `View.OnClickListener` interface. Then, simply set

```
textView.setOnClickListener(this);
```

And handle the click in your adapter class' `onClick` method. To know, for example, which row is clicked, add this line prior to the one above:

```
textView.setTag(position);
```

Then, in `onClick`, you can know which position in the list you are handling by getting this tag:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Object item = myList.get((Integer) v.getTag());
    //handle click event
}
```

Comment: Thus, a row would become a clickable listener, and convertView would reuse listener too. Beautiful and elegant solution :)
But, what I am looking for is a row, with 3 listeners, each of them behaves differently, so onClick implementation, wouldn't resolve the problem.